# How to get both docker ports which are mapped working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker to spin up 2 react apps (the app runs on port 9000 and I have an EXPOSE 9000 in the dockerfile for each of the react apps), however I'm only able to access one of them after running `docker-compose up`, the app sitting on localhost:1000 works. The other app sitting at localhost:2000 doesn't even attempt a page load in the browser, what might be going on?

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  client1:
    build: ./client/
    container_name: cc1
    ports:
      - '1000:9000'
    volumes:
      - './client:/workspace'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  client2:
    build: ./client-2/
    container_name: cc2
    ports:
      - '2000:9000'
    volumes:
      - './client-2:/workspace'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Running the below command gives this:

```
docker ps -a
```

| IMAGE | PORTS | NAMES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cc1 | 0.0.0.0:1000->9000/tcp | cc1 |
| cc2 | 0.0.0.0:2000->9000/tcp | cc2 |

Comment: From the given information, most likely scenario is that client 1 is working properly but client 2 is not. Have you ruled out the obvious, like does the container start up like is should?

Comment: EXPOSE in a Dockerfile doesn't actually *do* anything and should only be seen as documentation for which port(s) you think the container listens on. Make sure client2 actually listens on port 9000. Also, connecting the tty and stdin to both containers at once seems like it shouldn't work.

Comment: Does `client2` work if `client1` isn't running?  What does the code in the `client2` application to set up the network listener look like?  Is that container actually starting up?  Does overwriting the image's code with a bind mount cause problems (does deleting the `volumes:` help)?

Comment: both `client1` and `client2` are running off the same codebase (they're not pointed at the same directory, but the code is the same in the directories). Both of them run on port 9000. So in the docker-compose, I'm attempting to remap them into port 1000 and 2000. Both `tty` and `stdin` being `true` to both containers at once seems to work fine for me and I can read both app's logs, which say the web-dev-server has was launched successfully on port 9000.

Comment: maybe try checking `docker image history <your-image>` for more info about the image build